# Fast projection onto semidefinite cone

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigensystem, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Lots of algorithms for semidefinite programming make use of the Frobenius projection onto the cone of semidefinite matrices:
$$\mathcal{P}(A) = \min_{X\succeq0} \|A-X\|_{\mathrm{Fro}}^2.$$
Let's assume $A$ is symmetric.

The standard trick for this projection is to compute the eigendecomposition of $A$ as $A=X\Lambda X^\top$, where $\Lambda$ contains eigenvalues of $A$ and $X$ is an orthogonal set of eigenvectors.  Then, $\mathcal P(A)=X\max(\Lambda,0)X^\top.$  But, requires a full eigen-decomposition, which can be slow!

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525367/matrix-projection-on-a-cone) recommends computing the projection as $\mathcal{P}(A)=\frac{1}{2}(A+\sqrt{A^\top A})$, where $\sqrt{\cdot}$ denotes the matrix square root.  Disappointly, Matlab's `sqrtm()` is slower than `eig()` in my tests.

**What other algorithms could be used for this task?**

Stochastic and deterministic techniques are both OK, so long as they have some convergence guarantee (with high probability?).

Comment: Can you check out how matlab is computing `sqrtm` with `edit sqrtm`? My matlab is going through the complex Schur decomposition (`schur`), which is only slightly easier than a full eigendecomposition (which might use the Schur decomposition as well), which might explain why the `sqrtm` formula is not faster. There are other matrix-square-root algorithms that can be tried too.

Comment: My sqrtm references the following papers:
- N. J. Higham, Computing real square roots of a real matrix, Linear Algebra and Appl., 88/89 (1987), pp. 405-430.
- A. Bjorck and S. Hammarling, A Schur method for the square root of a matrix, Linear Algebra and Appl., 52/53 (1983), pp. 127-140.

I tried implementing some other iterative methods from Higham's "Matrix Functions" book with no luck speed-wise.  It appears eig() is hard to beat!

Comment: The documentation for sqrtm() says that it's using a block Schur decomposition and references the papers that Justin mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

You can potentially save some effort in the eigenvalue decomposition by finding only those eigenvalues (and the corresponding eigenvectors) that are greater than 0.   If most eigenvalues are non-negative, then you can find the negative eigenvalues and subtract off that part of the eigenvalue decomposition to compute the projection.   The LAPACK routine DSYEVR can be helpful.

I haven't found a faster way to do this computation yet, but I'd be interested in a faster approach to the projection that worked by way of the matrix square root or some other approach.

Comment: Thanks!  This definitely shaves off time in many cases, especially if we have some estimate of the spectrum a priori.  But somehow this projection seems like an "easier" problem than computing eigenvalues!  Maybe this intuition is wrong, though :-)